# Can't figure out this Error "The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following [this speed code tutorial](https://youtu.be/KO_PYJKHglo) and I'm facing some problems during somewhere on [5:08](https://youtu.be/KO_PYJKHglo?t=308).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class WaveColorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint? _paint;
  List<Color>? colors;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    colors = List.from(Colors.accents);
    colors!.removeRange(6, 13); //null safety
    List<Color> gradColors = colors.map(
      (color) => color.withOpacity(
        Random().nextDouble().clamp(0.5, 0.9),
      ),
    );
    final Gradient gradient = LinearGradient(colors: gradColors);

    _paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(
          0,
          20,
          size.width,
          40,
        ),
      );

    canvas.translate(0, size.height / 2);
    canvas.scale(1, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size.width.toInt(); i++) {
      double x = i.toDouble();
      double r = 2 * sin(i) - 2 * cos(4 * i) + sin(2 * i - pi * 24);
      r = r * 5;
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(x, r), Offset(x, -r), _paint!);
    } // frequency bar
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Up above is my code and I tried both `?` and `!` on every variables and functions but I can't figure out what the problem is.

And this is how my vscode looks right now:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using nullable dataType `List<Color>? colors;`, So it is possible to get null.

You can pass empty list on null case

```dart
    List<Color> gradColors = colors
            ?.map(
              (color) => color.withOpacity(
                Random().nextDouble().clamp(0.5, 0.9),
              ),
            )
            .toList() ??
        [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Yeasin Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157127/yeasin-sheikh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75309511/16124033), but here are two more ways:

```dart
List<Color> gradColors = colors == null ? [] : colors!.map((color) => color.withOpacity(Random().nextDouble().clamp(0.5, 0.9))).toList();
```

or

```dart
List<Color> gradColors = (colors ?? []).map((color) => color.withOpacity(Random().nextDouble().clamp(0.5, 0.9))).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works!
Could you explain what's the difference between your code and Yeasin Sheikh's code?
I'm a bit new to flutter so I can't really differentiate between the two answers :)

Comment: @loupdaniel actually it's the same logic just written differently. Also, I added another way

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more question.

Is their any tips about how to become more accustomed of writing codes in many ways within the same logic like you did?

Comment: @loupdaniel I don't have any hints to tell you. Actually I started out like you. The only secret is to always learn. One day you can write code in many ways with the same logic as mine